# Working with Interval literal for aliases in Snowflake

Tags: sql, subquery, alias, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query like this:

```
select to_date(current_date - interval 'b.a day') as date from (select 1 as a) as b
```

The expected result should be interval '1 day' which will then calculate the difference between the dates. Instead it throws the following error:

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'b'.
```

Comment: Because that `b.a` is appearing in single quotes, you are saying the interval is the string literal `b.a day` and that doesn't make sense. Why not just do `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - b.a FROM (SELECT 1 as a) as b` ?

Comment: Oh man why was I overthinking this. Thank you, this did the trick.

Comment: If you are wanting to be able to switch out that date part/interval easier (to add hours instead of days) you can consider something like this instead: `select TIMESTAMPADD(day, -b.a, current_date) from (select 1 as a) as b`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only need dates/days you can actually simplify this:

```
select to_date(current_date()) - b.a as date from (select 1 as a) as b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interval strings are not parsed to understand references to columns.  However, you can use intervals in arithmetic, so this should work:

```
select current_date - b.a * interval '1 day' as date
from (select 1 as a) b
```

`to_date()` is superfluous on an expression that is already a date.